# Xcode 8 Storyboards Blank

Tags: xcode, uiviewcontroller, storyboard, xcode8

For some reason in Xcode 8.1, all my storyboards are now blank, with boxes around where the content used to be:

[image]

I tried cleaning, deleting the Derived Data folder, and changing the size to Freeform but nothing has worked.

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try these:

1. Delete your derived data. Close xcode and clean, build again.
2. If option 1 not work then, Copy your project to another directory/folder. Close Xcode, open project from new directly and clean, build.